# How to get and order rows from different tables with a limit and offset?

Tags: web-services, list, postgresql

I'm creating web services to return a list of chats and notifications. The user can send as input the page number and the number of items to display per page, but 2 types of objects can be returned (from the newest to the latest) and must be displayed in the same list.

I have two tables `chat` and `notification`

```
CREATE TABLE chat
(
  idchat serial NOT NULL,
  idinterest integer NOT NULL,
  idowner integer NOT NULL,
  iduser integer NOT NULL,
  creationdate,
  editdate,
  CONSTRAINT pk_chat PRIMARY KEY (idchat)
)

CREATE TABLE notification
(
  idnotification serial NOT NULL,
  message character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  creationdate date NOT NULL,
  datefinvalidite date NOT NULL,
  idcompte integer NOT NULL,
  idtypenotification integer NOT NULL,
  sender integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT pk_notification PRIMARY KEY (idnotification)
)
```

I would like to create a view that groups all chats and notifications, composed of an id (`idchat` or `idnotification`), a date (`creationdate`), and a boolean `ischat`

But I don't know if this is the right solution.

**PROBLEMATIC**
If I have to return 20 rows of ordered messages (notifications and chats) I can either :

- Get 10 last notifications, then 10 last chats, but then the 9th chat might be much older than the 11th notification
- check the date of the newest chat, if the 20th newest notification is older, get only notifications, otherwise ... I don't know
- Get 20 newest notifications, 20 newest chats order them and send hem to the client but it could be a heavy task for a server that serves many requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select idchat id, creationdate, true ischat
from chat

union all

select idnotification id, creationdate, false ischat
from notification

order by creationdate desc limit 20
```

This version could be faster:

```
select *
from
    (
        (
            select idchat id, creationdate, true ischat
            from chat
            order by creationdate desc
            limit 20
        ) 

        union all

        (
            select idnotification id, creationdate, false ischat
            from notification
            order by creationdate desc
            limit 20
        ) 
    ) s

order by creationdate desc limit 20
```

Comment: It works if I remove `chat` and `notification` after their respective subqueries, thak you very much, I forgot that we could use `UNION` in postgresql